# Identify source of previous page

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here I have several forms and subforms in my access application. Say I have frmA and frmB  and both forms can access to frmC. In frmC, I want to check which form is clicked before from frmA or frmB, so I will have different display.

Is there anyway I can do that in my form onload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has direct insight to its "parent" in that sense, but you can use OpenArgs to store the form name.  Something like this could work:

Me!frmC.Form.OpenArgs = Me.Name

Maybe have the code run OnCurrent on your parent form(?).  Well, have to see where the code makes most sense to be placed.  But this will put the form name of the last-used parent form into the OpenArgs property of frmC. And then whenever you want access to the parent form name, you can refer to the OpenArgs of frmC.  Hope that helps.

Comment: No sorry, this won't work, I'm afraid - ReadOnly property.  I remembered differently, sorry.  However, it could still work if you are opening up a frmC from a closed state from whichever form using DoCmd.OpenForm and passing the name through OpenArgs.  Apologies again.